# iterate an object and create a new object with group by C# mvc

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

how do i loop through an object and create a new object in C# 
i have a view model  eg:

```
pViewModel  {
public itemFullName {get;set;}
public Item Item{get;set;}
}
public Item{
public int itemId{get;set;}
}
```

I want to create a new object after finding matching fullname but different id
so my new object will have a list of itemFullName, item.itemid(pipedelimited values for all the items in the previous list) in it.

Any help will be awesome.
thank you

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you're asking for. Can you provide some sample input and expected output? Maybe use JSON notation or something?

Comment: I have list<pviemodel> which has 237 items with duplicate itemfullname but with different set of item.itemid. I want to get a new list with duplicate itemfullname and item.itemid ( which is repeating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to group a list of your models by itemFullName. Here's how you might do that to create objects of an anonymous type.

```
var itemsAndIds = list
    .GroupBy(m => m.itemFullName, m => m.Item.itemId)
    .Select(g => new {ItemFullName = g.Key, ItemIds = string.Join("|", g)})
```

Comment: this is great. but if there are additional properties in the viewmodel say like "itemAddress" , itemCountry. is there a way to append those to the existing itemsandids object?

Comment: Yes, there are ways. For example, you could add new properties to the anonymous object for those. You'd probably want to change the second argument to GroupBy to `m => m.Item` and then select those difference parts as part of your Select (e.g. `g.Select(i => i.itemAddress)`)